# SSRS BIDS - Adding DLL references to a report project

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, bids

I'm am trying to introduce ZIP file output in SSRS. This required references to DLLS. I am following this tutorial:

[tut](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488883/Zip-Rendering-Extension-for-SQL-Server-Reporting-S#Build)

My Question is how can add a reference to a dll on a report project? In the solution explorer in BIDS i cannot see references under the solution? I can add a reference to a report but I need to add the reference to the report project then build.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tutorial:

> Because this is a normal .NET assembly project, BIDS is not necessary.

So you shouldn't be creating the new renderer DLL in a Report project; just create a standard Visual Studio -> Class Library project (or similar).

In a BIDS/VS Report project you can only add DLL references at the report level, i.e. not what you're looking to do.

Comment: I don't think its possible to create a standard visual studio class library project in BIDS?

Comment: That's correct, you'll need Visual Studio not BIDS to follow that tutorial. Your goal seems to be creating a DLL that the Report Server can use when exporting reports, which is independent of the actual report development that can be done in BIDS.

Comment: Cool, I'm downloading VS express hopefully get this done via that.